# Angular 5 + PDF.JS - Scrolling Issue

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf.js

I'm using Angular 5 with PDF.JS. I'm downloading a pdf and rendering it successfully. **I must show the pdf in a window, so i put the pdf in a div.**

```
<div class="container border">
<div id="OptionsPanel" class="row lighten-1" *ngIf="isLoaded === true">                  
            <div id = "Options" class="btn-group-justified mx-auto"> 
                    <div class="btn-group" id="Paging">
                            <button mat-icon-button class="mr-3" (click)="previousPage()" [disabled]="pageNumber === 1">
                                    <mat-icon class="menu-hamburger-icon">chevron_left</mat-icon>
                            </button> 
                            <input class="form-control input"
                                type="number"
                                [(ngModel)]="pageNumber"
                                pattern="[0-9]"                                                              
                                min="1"
                            /> <span style="margin-top:7px;">{{ page }} / {{ totalPages }}</span>
                        <button mat-icon-button (click)="nextPage()"  [disabled]="pageNumber === totalPages">
                                <mat-icon class="menu-hamburger-icon">chevron_right</mat-icon>
                        </button> 
                    </div>  
                    <span class="divider"></span>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                            <button mat-icon-button class="mr-3" (click)="incrementZoom(-0.1)" [disabled]="zoom === 0.5">
                                    <mat-icon class="menu-hamburger-icon">zoom_out</mat-icon>
                            </button> 
                            <input class="form-control input"
                                type="number"
                                [(ngModel)]="zoom"
                                placeholder="Zoom"
                                pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?"                                                             
                                min="0"
                            />
                        <button mat-icon-button (click)="incrementZoom(0.1)">
                                <mat-icon class="menu-hamburger-icon">zoom_in</mat-icon>
                        </button> 
                    </div>
                    <span class="divider" style="margin-left : 15px;"></span>
            </div>  
</div>
<div class="row bg-dark center-block mx-auto" id="PDF">        
    <pdf-viewer
        [src]="pdfSrc" 
        [render-text]="true"                          
        [zoom] = "zoom"
        [(page)]="pageNumber"
        [show-all]="true"
        [stick-to-page]="true"
        [original-size]="false"
        (after-load-complete)="afterLoadComplete($event)"
        style="display:block;">
    </pdf-viewer>     
</div>
```

```
#PDF{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 900px;
}
```

**I have an issue related scrolling. You can see a detailed picture below here ->**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCufS.png)

**So when i'm pressing to the nextPage button (which was an Click event), the whole webpage is scrolling down instead of the scroll of pdf's div.**

I have tried to remove the scroll of the body, but it doesn't help.
How can i solve this problem.

Comment: What does your 'nextPage()' Click event do? Can you post your .ts code?

Comment: nextPage()      { this.pageNumber++; }

Just a Click event, incrementing a pageNumber.

Answer (score 0):

I think your #PDF div belongs to the div.container.
if so, try setting height of div.container and overflow-y as hidden.

```
    div.container {
      height:100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    #PDF {
     height:100vh;
     overflow-y:scroll;
   }
```

Comment: Sanju M. thanks for your reply. I tried it, but it didn't help me.

Comment: is it possible to share something like plunker?